# How do you disable flexible space in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have been trying to learn Xcode/Swift on a part time basis.  My music player app was started in Xcode 7.3.1 with Swift 2.2 and I am now using Xcode 8.3.3 with Swift 3.1 with the same app.  I can't figure out why, when I click/touch the flexible space area, an action occurs?

```
    @IBOutlet var buttonToolbar: UIToolbar!

    var flexibleSpace: UIBarButtonItem!
    var rewind: UIBarButtonItem!
    var playPause: UIBarButtonItem!
    var fastForward: UIBarButtonItem!

    flexibleSpace?.isEnabled = false

    flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
    rewind = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.rewind, target: self, action: #selector(SongsViewController.rewindButton(_:)))
    playPause = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.play, target: self, action: #selector(SongsViewController.playPauseButton(_:)))
    fastForward = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.fastForward, target: self, action: #selector(SongsViewController.fastForwardButton(_:)))
    buttonToolbar.setItems([flexibleSpace, rewind, flexibleSpace, playPause, flexibleSpace, fastForward, flexibleSpace], animated: false)
```

For example, when I touch the left of the rewind button (in the flexible space region) rewind occurs, and when I touch to the right of the fast forward button (in that flexible space region) fast forward occurs.

I have tried setting the target to nil in for flexible space but it didn't help.

Could I have done something odd on the storyboard, if so, I can't find it.

Thanks, in advance, for any help.

Comment: Unless you're touching right in the middle between two bar-button items on a flexible space, it'll still register as a click event to the nearest button.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding.  Are you saying that flexible spaces, can not be shut off, that if you click them then you are really clicking the nearest item?  I know that I am clicking in the center of the flexible space.  Storyboard seems to show a very narrow strip in between the flexible space and the fast forward button, but I know I'm not clicking that area.  Do you think that .isEnabled = false should shut it off?